# How to change the color primary,color primarydark ,etc

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, themes

I am trying to make app which gives option to change the **color primary** ,**color primary dark** of the app. So the user has the option to change the colors as per the choice . I want to give this option in the setting .So the user can choose between *black* , *dark blue* ,*greyblue* ,etc .I know how to set the theme of the app in xml but I want to change the color of the hole app.
I want to change the theme of all the activity and dialog in the app .As one can not change the theme of the app as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509691/how-to-set-a-theme-to-whole-application-in-code-but-not-in-the-manifest) it is mentioned. this is why I want to make a different color file if possible

> 1. Will I have to make different color files as we have to do for different language?
> 2. If yes, How I can use the different color files then?

Comment: This is possible I know as most of the app gives this option.But how

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First step: make one theme per color-option in your `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MyAwesomeApp.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Your common styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAwesomeApp.Blue" parent="Theme.MyAwesomeApp.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_indigo_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_indigo_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_light_blue_A200</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAwesomeApp.Red" parent="Theme.MyAwesomeApp.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_red_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_red_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_red_A200</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Second step: Override the `onCreate()` method of your activity in order to call `setTheme()` with the choosen theme:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(getThemeIdChoosenByUser())
    setContentView(R.layout.myAwesomeLayout)
}
```

If you have more than one activity make a base class and set the them like this

```
public abstract class ThemeAwareBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(getThemeIdChoosenByUser());
    }

    private int getThemeIdChoosenByUser() {
        // Lookup in SharedPreferences etc.
    }
}

public class Activity1 extends ThemeAwareBaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_activity1)
        // do extra stuff on your resources, using findViewById on your layout_for_activity1
    }
}
```

Comment: so will I have to do this in all my activity?

Comment: What do you mean with "this all"?

Comment: As my app will contain multiple activity

Comment: Then just make one base-class for all your activities. Call `setTheme()` in your base class and `setContentView()` in your activities as ususal

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I tried the way but it gives an error with this This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor

Comment: Try using 'Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar' as base theme instead of 'Theme.AppCompat'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122616/discussion-between-neelay-srivastava-and-larsgrefer).